# Is face swapping in movies/3D videos possible using the Intel RealSense SDK?

Tags: realsense

I want to swap Cinderella face with mine, throughout the whole 3D Cinderella(example) movies. Is it possible with the Intel real sense SDK?

Through camera we can scan and get our 3D scan face object. But I'm not aware if we could swap that scan face in the videos/movies.

I'm using this realsense camera with Window application(C#).

Answer (score 0):

Intel RealSense SDK provides modules for BGS (background substitution) and for working with one's face - like using an avatar (or blockhead) face. one that in realtime moves with your actual facial movements - but it's meant for working with live video - perhaps to make a movie. Not to edit a movie already made.  You can enhance photography but that also isn't what you seem to be asking about.

Comment: While searching I came across this solution of using Oddcast 3D VideoStar oddcast.com/widgets/videostar , but it is paid.Can you suggest suggest any free API which could do same task?